# Serialized Python object to JSON, but its function not working in javascript

Tags: jquery, python, django, json, django-models

I'm trying to use .get() in jQuery to send a request to server and return a python object using Django framework. 
By using

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', ExampleModel.objects.all())
return HttpResponse(data, 'application/json')
```

I can get a collection of objects at javascript end like this: [object Object][object Object]
But it seems impossible to call any parameters or functions from those objects. I've tried this:

```
for (x in data){
    alert(data[x].parameter);
}
```

I just get several "undefined" as a result. Can anybody explain why? Thanks.

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` and `console.log(x)` and show some results here so we can see the structure of the objects.

Comment: `console.dir` might give you something more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Django's JSON serializer puts each object in complex structure like `{'id': 123, 'model': 'app.Model', fields:{'name': 'blah', 'active': true}}` so you'll need to retrieve values properly in JS. You can use Firebug for Firefox or Web Inspector for Chrome to set a breakpoint inside your callback and introspect received data.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I can retrieve values from returned objects now. Just one more thing: I did not found the functions from my Django model in these JS objects. Is it possible to pass them in JSON?

Comment: Automatically - no. But you can construct any structure in Python and put it through `simplejson.dumps()` to receive any data you need.

Comment: You can say "thanks" by approving and/or upvoting one or more of our answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you was accessing undefined `parameter`. Take ilvar's example,

```
eval('data='+"{'id': 123, 'model': 'app.Model', fields:{'name': 'blah', 'active': true}}")
for (var x in data){
    console.info(x, '=>', data[x])
}
// will outputs
id => 123
model => app.Model
fields => Object
```

None of the `123`, `"app.Model"` or `Object` has `parameter` property

Comment: Thanks for the info! I can retrieve properties from my models now. One more thing: I still cannot find the functions defined in my models after passing them to javascript. What can I do with that?

Comment: The json only contains data from server-side model instances, you need client-side javascript functions to operate on the data.